# GLM in R - weight parameter

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, weights

I'm trying to understand what the weight parameter does in a GLM in R:

```
df <- data.frame('resp' = c(0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,1,0,0),
                 'type' = c('Loc1','Loc2','Loc3','Loc1','Loc2','Loc2','Loc3','Loc1','Loc2','Loc2','Loc1'),
                 'wgt' = c(1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1))


model1 <- glm(resp ~ type, family = poisson, weight=wgt, data = df)
model2 <- glm(resp ~ type, family = poisson, weight=wgt, data = df[df$wgt>0,])

sum(model1$fitted.values) == sum(df$resp) # FALSE
sum(model2$fitted.values) == sum(df[df$wgt>0,]$resp) # TRUE
```

According to https://www.towerswatson.com/DownloadMedia.aspx?media=%7BE7F1DAFE-D085-4169-81CE-C22ED018FBA3%7D

page 17, the weight parameter will flow into variance of the response. I have two questions of this:

1. If it's the case the weight will divide the variance function then why is R not returning an error when fitting a glm with a weight parameter with 0 values as I thought we'd be dividing by 0?
2. If we fit with the weight with values of 0, the mean of the fitted values is not equal to the response. Excluding the non zero weights, the mean is equal to the response. Why is this the case?

Comment: Weights usually *multiply* observations.  Thus, unless you have *authoritative* evidence to the contrary, that's what you should assume.  The help page for `glm` explains the intended uses of this parameter.

Comment: Could you expand at all, what do you mean by multiply observations? It does not state this in the help page.

Comment: The help page gives three examples of the uses of weights, all of which imply they are used multiplicatively: as inversely proportional to dispersion, to count numbers of observations used to form means, and as proportional to numbers of trials.

Comment: @whuber; OK I don't see your point. It does not mean multiply observations it, the documentation states it's inversely proportion to the dispersion factor, so 1/w_i * dispersion and I am curious why it doesn't error if I give it a 0 weight

Comment: If you give it zero weight it probably just omits that observation, it seems the only reasonable thing to do!